# Reduction and decidability

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, reductions, proof-techniques, undecidability

Consider the following language: $$ L = \{ \langle M \rangle \ |\ M \text { accepts } w \text { whenever it accepts } w^R \}$$

I am trying to understand the following proof that this language $L$ is undecidable.

The proof proceeds by contradiction, by reducing to $L$ the language  $A_{TM}=\{\langle M,w \rangle\mid M\text{ accepts }w\}$ known to be undecidable. It goes as follows:

Suppose that $L$ is decidable, then there's a TM $M_L$, that decides $L$

Thus we can build $M_{ATM}$ to decide $A_{TM}$ as follows:

1. Let $\langle M, w \rangle$ be an input for $M_{ATM}$.
2. Construct a machine, $M_1$ which on input $x$: Simulate $M$ on $w$; if $M$ rejects $w$, $reject$.  If $M$ accepts $w$, $accept$ if $x=01$, $reject$ otherwise.
3. Simulate $M_L$ on input $\langle M_1 \rangle$.
4. $accept$ if $M_L$ rejects. $reject$ otherwise.

Since $A_{TM}$ is not decidable, we have a contradiction, which implies that $L$ cannot be decidable.

However there is a point of the proof I do not understand.

**My question is:** What happens if $M$ gets into a loop on some $w$?

Comment: What is $A_{TM}$ ? Can you try to improve the readability? What are you trying to prove? What is the purpose of your construction?

Comment: Of course. $A_{TM}$ is a common notation for the (undecidable) language $$\{ \langle M,w \rangle \ | \ \text { TM M accepts w } \}$$

Comment: I am trying to prove by contradiction (using reduction to $A_{TM}$) that $L$ is undecidable language.

Comment: Thanks. That is what is needed so that people understand what you are at.`It should be in the text of your question, explaining why you are doing all that. Also, do not assume too much in notations when talking to the planet, it is sometimes noted $ATM$, but ATM can also mean Alternating Turing Machine (whatever that is). I personally did not know this notation as standard, and I noticed on the web that many people still give the definition.

Comment: Actually I think you are trying to reduce $A_{TM}$ to $L$, to prove
the undecidability of $L$, since $A_{TM}$ is known to be
undecidable. But why won't you say it explicitly in your question? Are
you afraid it might help the reader?  I am not trying to give you a
hard time. You essentially ask questions, and asking them well saves
time for everyone, including you.

Comment: I actually thinks this proof reduces $L$ to $A_{TM}$ but let's set semantics aside. This is a proof by contradiction; We assume there's a TM which decides $L$ and then we show that using this TM we could decide $A_{TM}$. My question is regarding the case where $M$ doesn't halt on some $w$.

Comment: "[*In computability theory, a Turing reduction from a problem A to a
problem B, is a reduction which solves A, assuming the solution to B
is already
known*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction)". You assume
decidability of $L$ is known. The fact that $M$ does not halt, or
rejects is immaterial. What you want is that the language accepted by
$M_1$ is $\{01\}$ iff $M$ accepts $w$ (and is $\emptyset$
otherwise. If $M$ loops, thus not acceptin $w$, then $M_1$ loops on
any input, recognizing $\emptyset$. Hence $M_L$ will accept $\langle
M_1 \rangle$, so that $M_{ATM}$ will reject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many problems like this, it's often a bad idea to base your construction on both acceptance and rejection. Try rewriting your $M_1$ in this form

```
M1(x) =
   simulate M on w
   if M accepts w
      if x = 01
         accept
```

Now the important thing is that

1. If $M$ accepts $w$ (i.e., if $\langle M, w\rangle\in A_{TM}$) then $L(M_1)=\{01\}$.
2. If $M$ fails to accept $w$, *either by rejecting or by running forever*, then $M_1$ will accept nothing, so $L(M_1)=\varnothing$

Now if $L$ were decidable with decider $M_L$, then you can use the decider and $M_1$ to build a decider, $M_A$, for $A_{TM}$ as you suggested:

```
MA(<M>, w) = 
   Construct M1 as above
   if ML accepts <M1>
      reject
   else if ML rejects <M1>
      accept
```

Now we have

1. If $M$ accepts $w$, then $L(M_1)=\{01\}$ so $M_L$ will reject $M_1$ and hence $M_A$ will accept $\langle M, w\rangle$.
2. If $M$ doesn't accept $w$, then $L(M_1)=\varnothing$  so $M_L$ will accept $M_1$ and hence $M_A$ will reject $\langle M, w\rangle$.

In short, $M_A$ is indeed a decider for $A_{TM}$, an undecidable language, meaning that $L$ must not be decidable.

Answer (score 2):

In this reduction of $A_{TM}=\{\langle M,w \rangle\mid M\text{ accepts }w\}$ to $L$, what matters in the construction of the Turing machine $M_1$ is  that the language accepted by
$M_1$ is $\{01\}$ iff $M$ accepts $w$, and is $\emptyset$
otherwise.

Whether $M$ does not halt on input $w$, or halts rejecting it, does not make any difference. In both cases, the language accepted by $M_1$ is  $\emptyset$, thus satisfyiing the definition for $L$. Hence $M_L$ will accept $\langle
M_1 \rangle$, so that $M_{ATM}$ will reject.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to prove that $L$ is undecidable by showing $A_{tm}\le L$.

For this reduction to be valid, you need to convert each input $(\langle M \rangle, w)$ of $A_{tm}$ into an input $\langle M_1 \rangle$ (using your notations) for $L$ so that
$$ (\langle M \rangle, w) \in A_{tm} \quad\text{ iff }\quad \langle M_1 \rangle \in L$$

Equivalently, such a reduction shows that if you can decide $L$ you will be able to decide $A_{tm}$: simply you convert the input of $A_{tm}$ to an equivalent input of $L$ and run $M_L$ on it.

So the question that hides in your post, is how to convert the inputs.
Let's see what happens in each case:

1. **case I**: $(\langle M \rangle, w) \in A_{tm}$.
   In this case $M_1$ will just run $M$ on $w$ (which ends in an accepting state, and specifically, always halts), and then only accepts $x=01$. Therefore $M_1$ is not in $L$.
2. **case II**: $(\langle M \rangle, w) \notin A_{tm}$.
   As you mention, there are 2 cases here: wither $M$ rejects $w$ or it never halts. In both cases, $M_1$ never accept a single word: either it rejects *everything*, or it never halts (and then also no input is ever accepted). Therefore $M_1$ is in $L$ (vacuously satisfying the requirement).

So this goes the opposite way from the "iff" statement I wrote above, but that's fine because the final decision of your $M_{ATM}$ is the *opposite* of the decision of $M_L$ on $M_1$, which fixes this negaiton. So everything works fine, and the proof is valid. Makes sense?

Comment: Now, I am curious to see what happens.

Comment: I spent considerable time trying to explain to the OP how to make a question clearer. But I am afraid it was wasted. The problem is that we can work out what he intends, but the work is useless for further users as understanding what is the issue is to hard. Hence they will not bother reading at all. The question should not have to be explained in answers ,,, Working on question quality is the proper way to say "please" and "thank you"  cc @Elimination

Comment: I appreciate your criticism, @babou

Comment: Thanks. I edited your question to make it easier for future users. You can thus see what I meant. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong solution ( based on the comment below )

> L={⟨M⟩ | M accepts w whenever it accepts $w^R$}. Proof by
>   contradiction. Assume that L is decidable and let $R$ be a decider for
>   it. We will construct decider $S$ for $A_{tm}$, using $R$ as a
>   subrouting. Note that $A_{tm}$ = {`<M,w> | M is a TM and M accepts
>   w`}.
>
> ```
> S = on input <M,w>
> constructs M_w = on input x
> if x!=010 reject
> else run M on w
>  if M accepts w => accept
>  else reject
> Run R on M_w
> if R accepts => accept
> if R rejects => reject
> ```
>
> Note: if $M$ accepts $w$ then $L(M_w)$ = {010} , $R$ ran on $M_w$ will
>   accept, therefore $S$ will accept. if $M$ rejects or loops on $w$ then
>   $L(M_w)$ = empty set , $R$ ran on $M_w$ will reject, therefore $S$
>   will reject. We have built a decider for $A_{tm}$, since we know that
>   $A_{tm} $ is undecidable our assumption was wrong => L is undecidable.

Edited Solution>>>

L={⟨M⟩ | M accepts w whenever it accepts $w^R$}. Proof by contradiction.
Assume that L is decidable and let $R$ be a decider for it.
We will construct decider $S$ for $A_{tm}$, using $R$ as a subrouting. Note that $A_{tm}$ = {`<M,w>` | M is a TM and M accepts w`}.

```
S = on input <M,w>
constructs M_w = on input x
run M on w
 if M accepts w => reject
 else  => accept
Run R on M_w
if R accepts => accept
if R rejects => reject
```

Note: if $M$ accepts $w$ then $M_w$ will reject on all input $L(M_w)$ = empty set, $R$ ran on $M_w$ will accept, therefore $S$ will accept. if $M$ rejects or loops on $w$ then $L(M_w)$ = {$\Sigma^*$} , $R$ ran on $M_w$ will reject , therefore $S$ will reject.
We have built a decider for $A_{tm}$, since we know that $A_{tm} $ is undecidable our assumption was wrong => L is undecidable.

Comment: This solution doesn't work: R will always accept on $M_w$, since either $L(M) = \emptyset$ or $L(M) = \{ 010 \}$, and in both cases $L(M)$ is closed under string reversal.

Comment: Can you please clarify - $L(M) $ is closed under string reversal ? (Sipser): A collection of objects is closed under some operation if applying that operation to members of the collection returns an object still in the collection. Now empty set contains no elements.

Comment: The empty set is closed under reversal vacuously. You can prove this using the definition – if you apply reversal to a member of the collection, you get another member of the collection. You can easily check that this holds for the empty set.