# Is the set of all strings over a finite alphabet finite?

Tags: formal-languages, word-combinatorics, kleene-star

Suppose $Σ=\{0,1\}$;  then $Σ^*$ is the set of all strings over $Σ$.

Is $Σ^*$ over $Σ$ finte?

Comment: did you look at [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Kleene_star) to see what $\Sigma^*$ actually means?

Comment: Yes, I know what it means, but is |  Σ* | finite or not ?

Comment: can you specify some words that belong to $\Sigma^*$? how many of these can you specify (more than 2? more than 3? how about more than 10?)

Comment: **The answer is: Σ* does not have a length.** The reason for it is that Σ* is a set of strings, an infinite set of strings, which are all of finite length. The notation |Σ*| is for the cardinality of Σ*, i.e. its number of elements, which as I said is infinite.

Comment: Thanks babou. Well, I guess I deserved that one for [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43089/reduction-and-decidability/43093#comment86543_43093)  (;

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your question is a very basic one. Since you [did not include much of an attempt to solve it on your own](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594), we have little to work with. Let me direct you towards our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599) which cover your problem in detail. Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific problems you encountered. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The star operator is a unary operator known as Kleene star (or Kleene closure) and the result of its application on $\Sigma$ (an arbitrary set of strings) is another set that contains all possible finite strings constructed using only strings from $\Sigma$.

Assuming that the set contains at least one non-empty string, the cardinality of the set produced by the Kleene star operator is infinite since we can always generate a new unique string by appending one of the non-empty strings.

Comment: Actually the Kleene closure applies to sets of strings, and the use with alphabets, i.e. sets of symbols, is an extension considering each alphabet as a set of strings of length 1.(just for the sake of precision).

Comment: Actually, it is not true that Kleene star **always** produces an infinite set. counterexamples: $\emptyset^*$, and $\{\varepsilon\}^*$.