# Can any problem that runs in exponential time on a deterministic RAM be run in polynomial time on a non-deterministic RAM?

Tags: complexity-theory

If P is a program that can be run in exponential time on a deterministic RAM. Can P always be run in polynomial time on a non-deterministic RAM?

Comment: I notice that you submitted an edit to [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43671/is-%ce%a3%e2%88%97-finite), in which you tried to change the question from "Is $\Sigma^*$ finite?" to "Is $\Sigma^*$ countable?" Please don't make edits that completely change the meaning of somebody else's question, especially when the edit invalidates the existing answers false.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know, but probably not.

You shouldn't equate nondeterministic polynomial computation with deterministic exponential computation. A problem being **NP**-complete does mean that we probably don't know anything better than an exponential deterministic algorithm for it; however, there are a great many exponential deterministic algorithms for which we don't know any nondeterministic polynomial algorithms (e.g., anything that's **EXP**-complete).

There's no particular reason to assume that **EXP**$\,=\,$**NP**. In particular, exponential-time algorithms are allowed to use an exponential amount of storage, but any computation path of a polynomial-time computation can only use a polynomial amount.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a program that prints all the subsets of a set. There are an exponential number of those and a non-deterministic RAM doesn't make the process any faster. So I'd say the answer is no.